# TensorFlow output in the wrong range

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, classification

I am training a simple single-layer NN for binary classification with TensorFlow. My training data has the labels 0 and 1, the training of the NN seems ok for now, I get accuracy values of ~80% and a AUC value of ~75%. So the training seems fine, so far. If I now try to evaluate some data using the model, the output-score is not in the expected range. The expected outputs should be in the range `[0,1]` but they are more like in the range of `[0.1,0.35`]. This is the code I use for the training:

```
# initialize model
model = keras.models.Sequential()

# get input-dimension
arr = LoadTTree(self,file=self.TrainTreeDir,print=False)
self.InputDimension = len(arr[0][0])
  
# build the input layer
model.add(keras.Input(shape = (self.InputDimension), name = "inputlayer"))
# build the hidden layer
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(self.Nodes, name = "hiddenlayer", activation = self.ActivationFunction)
# build the output layer
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(self.OutputDimension, activation=self.OutputActivation, name="output_layer",))

# build KerasModel, compile and print model-summary 
self.KerasModel = model
self.KerasModel.compile(loss = Loss(self), optimizer = Optimizer(self), weighted_metrics = self.Metrics)
self.KerasModel.summary()
```

with the following values

`ActivationFunction = sigmoid, OutputActivation = sigmoid, Loss = binary_crossentropy, Optimizer = adam`

Training is done as follows

```
hist = self.KerasModel.fit(self.data_train, self.labels_train, epochs=self.Epochs, batch_size=self.BatchSize, 
         verbose=self.Verbosity, sample_weight=self.weights_train, validation_data=(self.data_val,self.labels_val,self.weights_val))
```

With `Epochs = 50`.

I already tried playing around with the loss- and activation functions, but that did not solve my problem.

Does anybody now why my model does not output the correct range of values?

Comment: Do you happen to have an un-balanced dataset and your model just "learned" to return values < 0.5 (which is then interpreted as 0)?

Comment: @HansQ Yes the dataset is indeed unbalanced, but I compute a train_weight for every array that is put into the model. So for every input array I give I have a train_weight that I then put into the training with the `sample_weight` parameter. The weights are quite small for the background processes and bigger for the signal process, which has way lower statistics in the dataset.

Comment: After training, check model.get_weights(). Check if the weights are well initialized.